# Retrieve parameter that without prarameter name

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a registration and activation code that I am updating a bit, after the user registers it sends them a email to activate.

Link emailed

```
/user/activate/$hashed_confirm_code
```

which generates

```
http://example.com/user/activate/0dbc0aef3d4d9d3e67ee4bf6c
```

I went to http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/ and did a mod rewrite changed the email link accordingly.

rewrite is on

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)hash_token=($|&)
RewriteRule ^user/activate$ /user/activate/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

if i click the link it produces the following in the browser

http://example.com/user/activate/0dbc0aef3d4d9d3e67ee4bf6c

however it just gives a 500 error, the basics of my activation code function is

```
function activate_user(){

    if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET") && isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {

        $confirm_code = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

       //do stuff


    }
}
```

now if i change the link in the browser

```
example.com/user/activate/0dbc0aef3d4d9d3e67ee4bf6c93c
```

to this

```
example.com/user/activate?0dbc0aef3d4d9d3e67ee4bf6c
```

it works, so if i remove the forward slash and add the question mark it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite mode is not correct, you should get the matched variable and pass it tho the file (here I assumed it called `activate.php`) as a query string parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^user/activate/([^/]+)/?$ user/activate.php?code=$1 [L,NC]
```

PS: I used following flags:

`L` to cause `mod_rewrite` to stop processing the rule set.

`NC` to cause the `RewriteRule` to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

You can also use `QSA` to make the query strings get combined.

**Update:**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

These two rules will create a loop, why? Because first one says if you get a request that contains `.php`, go ahead and remove the `.php` file and second one indicates if you received a request that would be valid file name if we add `.php`, go ahead and add the extension to it. The important thing that you need to consider is whenever you change the url, apache starts from top and tries to mach with the new url.
To prevent that you can use at top of the file:

```
#PREVENT SECOND EVALUATION
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I got the same result

Comment: @Devflow if you remove "RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R], would it work?

Comment: hey i tried to add a second link based of you first answer and it only returns 1 parameter but in this link there is 2

Comment: @Devflow you can use QSA flag as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: thats not the problem `RewriteRule ^user/password-reset/([^/]*)([^/]*)?$ user/password-reset.php?reset_token=$1&token=$2 [L,NC]` when i var dump reset_token it shows when i vardump token it shows 0

Comment: @Devflow you should add a / between them ([^/]*)/([^/]*)

Comment: it fails to rewrite if i do

Comment: @Devflow also you need another one just before the last question mark: /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?